# SUMIF in excel Pandas formula

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do SUMIFS style calculations using pandas 
The first unloading is at 10:00, the second in an hour at 11:00, and so on 
Hourly analytics 
I need to subtract the first from the second (11:00 - 10:00)
 Example:

1 - data frame

```
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
| Time  | Id | Cost | Show | Link_cliks | Install |
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
| 10:00 |  1 |   25 |  500 |         10 |       3 |
| 10:00 |  2 |   15 |  300 |          8 |       2 |
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
```

2 - data frame

```
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
| Time  | Id | Cost | Show | Link_cliks | Install |
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
| 11:00 |  1 |   30 |  600 |         12 |       4 |
| 11:00 |  2 |   18 |  350 |          9 |       0 |
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
```

I would like to receive:

```
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
| Time  | Id | Cost | Show | Link_cliks | Install |
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+
| 10:00 |  1 |   25 |  500 |         10 |       3 |
| 10:00 |  2 |   15 |  300 |          8 |       2 |
| 11:00 |  1 |    5 |  100 |          2 |       1 |
| 11:00 |  2 |    3 |   50 |          1 |       0 |
+-------+----+------+------+------------+---------+

11:00, id 1, Cost column -- Excel formula (30 - SUMIF(1df.Cost;1df.id;2df.id)) = 30 - 25 = 5
```

Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: I need to subtract the second from the first df. 
For example the column Cost for 11:00. id 1:
(Time "11:00", id "1", Cost "30") - (Time "10:00", id "1", Cost "25") = (30-25)=  Cost 5

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making an intermediary df and joining the two data frames on the relevant columns, in this case `Id`. That way you can construct the formula you want for matching columns and then unpack the results.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
{'Time': '10:00', 'Id': 1, 'Cost': 25},
{'Time': '10:00', 'Id': 2, 'Cost': 15}
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{'Time': '11:00', 'Id': 1, 'Cost': 30},
{'Time': '11:00', 'Id': 2, 'Cost': 18}
])

df = df1.merge(df2,  on=['Id'], suffixes=('_x', ''))

df['Cost'] = df['Cost'] - df['Cost_x']

df_final = df1.append(df.loc[:, ['Time', 'Id', 'Cost']])
```

Comment: Great - If the answer worked for you, you can accept the answer to show this